# rendering image with GatsbyImage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I'm unable to render a dynamic image coming from strapi cms using `GatsbyImage` from `gatsby-plugin-image`
Everything worked fine with the old `gatsby-image` plugin, really don't know what i'm doing wrong here.

`Warning: Failed prop type: The prop` src`is marked as required in`J`, but its value is` undefined`.`

How should i use the `image` object or the `getImage()` function to render the `GatsbyImage` ?

```
export const query = graphql`
  {
    allStrapiProjects(filter: { featured: { eq: true } }) {
      nodes {
        title
        image {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
              fluid {
                ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

```
import { GatsbyImage, getImage, StaticImage } from "gatsby-plugin-image";


const Project = ({
  image,
}: any) => {
  const gatsbyImg = getImage(image);
  const imgPath = image.localFile.childImageSharp.fluid;
  console.log("gatsbyImg:", gatsbyImg);
  console.log("image:", image);
  console.log("imgPath:", imgPath);

  return (
   ...
   <GatsbyImage image={imgPath} alt={"alt"} />
   )
```

Output result for the console logs above:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, the issue appears because of the mix of GraphQL nodes between `gatsby-image` and `gatsby-plugin-image`. Summarizing a lot, your queryable node should be `gatsyImageData` instead of `fluid` or `fixed`.

This is the previous syntax:
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

```
export const query = graphql`
  {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "images/example.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        fixed {
          ...GatsbyImageSharpFixed
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

While the new one looks like:

```
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

export const query = graphql`
  {
    file(relativePath: { eq: "images/example.jpg" }) {
      childImageSharp {
        gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
      }
    }
  }
`
```

*Check further details in the [migration guide](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/)*

The problem is that you are querying the old GraphQL node (fluid or fixed) that worked for `Img` (from `gatsby-image`) while the new component, `GatsbyImage` requires an `image` prop, extracted from `gatsbyImageData` node.

That said, `getImage` is a helper function (not mandatory) that helps you to clean up the code.

Double-check the following steps:

- Install the dependencies:

  ```
  npm install gatsby-plugin-image gatsby-plugin-sharp gatsby-transformer-sharp
  ```
- Remove the old `gatsby-image` dependency references if any.
- Clean the cache
- Query the proper nodes: check them in `localhost:8000/___graphiql`
- (Optional) run the codemod:

  ```
  npx gatsby-codemods gatsby-plugin-image <optional-path>
  ```

  This will automatically adapt your old code to the new syntax.

In the end, your code should look like:

```
export const query = graphql`
  {
    allStrapiProjects(filter: { featured: { eq: true } }) {
      nodes {
        title
        image {
          localFile {
            childImageSharp {
             gatsbyImageData(layout: FIXED)
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Your component should work alone since now is not working because it's not getting the proper data.